# How to place a picture and text on one line?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I need the picture and text to be on the same line. Who understands layout, how can this be done? As soon as I set the style of the text, it immediately slides under the image

[image]

this is my code

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <a href="#"><img src="{{asset('img/stores/itunes.png')}}" width="80"></a>
                        <h4 style="font-size: 1.2rem; color: #1b1e21; margin-top: 5px">iTunes</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 text text-right">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark" value="Слушать">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
      <a href="#"><img src="{{asset('img/stores/itunes.png')}}" width="80"></a>
      <h4 style="font-size: 1.2rem; color: #1b1e21; margin-top: 5px">iTunes</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 text text-right">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark" value="Слушать">
  </div>
</div>
```